# Difficulty Understanding Logic of Joines

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'll use the following query to illustrate my question:

```
select a.shipperid,
       b.orderid,
       b.custid
from shippers a inner join orders b

on a.shipperid = b.shipperid
```

Shipperid is the primary key in the shippers table, and it is also the foreign key in the orders table.
There are only three shipping IDs, and each of them is associated with many different orders in the order table.  The join will match the tables when the shipper IDs match.

However, each of the shipper IDs in the shippers table is associated with many, many different rows in the orders table.

So, how do I know that the rows in the shippers table aren't being match with the rows in the orders table in an arbitrary manner?

Comment: Here is an excellent article to help you understand joins a bit better going forward: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/. I hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by an arbitrary manner?  With an inner join, every row of one columns value will be matched with every equal value in the other table.

Comment: Well, a.shipperid will be equal to b.shipperid in many different instances.  So, how do I know that the rows the the two tables are not joined in an arbitrary manner.

Comment: There is no order inherent in a set based system.  So, they are joined in a random order.  However you can be assured that the value of the one table will always be joined to its equal in the other table.  The way to specify order is by using the `order by` clause. Does that make sense? Or am I over simplifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current query you are doing inner join which will give you output of only matching lines::

[image: Joins]

See in the image below for your better understanding.

So to answer your question, you need to do Left join in your case like::

```
select a.shipperid,
       b.orderid,
       b.custid
from shippers a 
left join orders b

on a.shipperid = b.shipperid
```

the result of this will be with null value of Orders if there is not any order on that shipping.

Answer (score 0):

your query only asks to get all the (shipper id, orderid, custid) tuples that could possibly be related to each other.  In other words, for each tuple returned, then shipperid has at some point shipped orderid to custid.  Now it is up to you if you want to to further constrain the query to narrow down to a subset of the results on other criteria.