# Inner Joins with Derived Tables

Tags: sql, inner-join, derived-table

I have a question about the basic syntax of joining with derived tables.

Is this teh basic syntax that is used:

```
select *
from table1 a

inner join (select * from table2) as T1

on 1.ID = T1.ID
```

Will that work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559392/difficulty-understanding-logic-of-joines#answer-26559409

Comment: I'm asking about joining to derived tables.  In my previous question, I did not ask about derived tables.

Comment: change 1.id to a.id and try it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you're asking about joining two subqueries?
try:

```
select * from
(select * from table1) t1 inner join
(select * from table2) t2 on
t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: So, if I place the derived table in the JOIN clause (as you did above), I can join it to other tables in my query?

Answer (score 1):

In your posted query change `on 1.ID = T1.ID` to `on a.ID = T1.ID` and it should work fine but why do you even need that? You can directly join with `table1` and no need of inline/derived table like

```
select *
from table1 a
inner join 
table2 T1
on a.ID = T1.ID
```

Comment: Okay, thanks Rahul.  You and Beth both gave pretty good answers. I'll mark hers as the answer, but only because she posted first.  

But thank you so much for your help.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Also useful if you're trying to use derived table defined using `VALUES`, i.e., to get around the 1000 row limit on inserts to temporary tables ([multiple row insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624713/insert-multiple-rows-without-repeating-the-insert-into-part-of-the-stateme)).  Make sure to specify the names of the variables/columns in the VALUES statement i.e., `(ids)`, after the alias i.e., `v`.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1,'c1'),(2,'c2'),(3,'c3')) v (ids, textcol)
JOIN TABLE1 t1 on t1.ids = v.ids
```